# Why does single quote not work with string interpolation in ruby

Tags: ruby

I tried string interpolation with single quotes using `#{}` but it does not work. When I tried it with double quotes it works. Please explain to me why this is so, if it's possible to do string interpolation with single quotes and how to do so in ruby if it is possible.

Comment: This question looks a little strange, its just a syntax convention.

Comment: Because that's how single- and double-quoted strings work in Ruby.

Comment: Duplicated question: _Why interpolation with single quotes not working but with double quotes works in c#_ ;)

Comment: The poster understands string interpolation using double-quotes. The question is why string interpolation is not performed with single-quoted strings, which is more-or-less the same as asking *why* Ruby provides a way to define strings (using single quotes) that disregards string interpolation directives within strings (e.g., `#{...}` and `%`).

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please? What kind of answer are you looking for other than "the language specification says so"? If you want to know why the language specification says so, that is a question you will have to ask matz.

Comment: @omokehindeigbekoyi : Because [Matz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukihiro_Matsumoto) in his infinited wisdom decided it in this way for the benefit of us mere mortals, who, because of this, have the benefit that Ruby is easy to learn, because the interpolation rules are now similar in spirit to those of many other well-known languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby doesn't interpret single-quoted strings.

This might seem like a limitation at first, but it's actually a nice feature. It allows you to enter many characters without having to escape them, which results in more legible code:

```
file = 'C:\foo\bar\baz.txt'

# as opposed to:

file = "C:\\foo\\bar\\baz.txt"
```

Or when having a string about string interpolation itself: (note that Stack Overflow's syntax highlighting is misleading – there's *no* interpolation)

```
string = 'In Ruby, you can write "1 + 2 = #{ 1 + 2 }" to get "1 + 2 = 3".'

# instead of:

string = "In Ruby, you can write \"1 + 2 = \#{ 1 + 2 }\" to get \"1 + 2 = 3\"."
```

Apart from `'...'` and `"..."`, Ruby also has `%q(...)` and `%Q(...)` style string literals (the former without, the latter with interpolation). This is especially useful if your string contains both, single and double quotes:

```
string = %q(A string containing '...' and "...")
```

You can even pick your own delimiter: (again, the syntax highlighter can't keep up)

```
string = %q@A string containing '...', "..." and (...)"@
```

And finally, you can mix and match different string literal styles:

```
string = %q(foo) 'bar' "baz"
#=> "foobarbaz"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how ruby language is designed.
From language docs: [Literals](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings)

> Double-quote strings allow escaped characters such as \n for newline,
> \t for tab, etc.
> Double-quote strings allow interpolation of other
> values using #{...}:

```
value = 10
puts "Test value is #{value}"
# => Test value is 10
```

> Interpolation may be disabled by escaping the “#” character or **using single-quote strings**

```
puts 'Test value is #{value}'
# => Test value is #{value}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Single-Quoted Strings and Escapes/Expressions

That's just how the language is defined: you can't interpolate using the embedded expression operator (`#{}`) within a single-quoted string. Unlike double-quoted strings, single-quoted strings aren't scanned for embedded expressions or most escapes. This is important when you need to do things like printing escape characters or unevaluated expressions such as:

```
puts 'This is a newline character: \n'
puts 'This is how you embed an expression: #{foo}'
```

That doesn't mean you can't approximate interpolation with single-quoted strings in other ways. For example:

```
'foo: %s' % 'bar'
#=> "foo: bar"

sprintf '%d, %d, %d', 1, 2, 3
#=> "1, 2, 3"
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch this is explains everything a lot better. I just needed a clarification on why this is so in ruby, if it is possible to interpolate with single quotes in ruby and how to do that. You have answered the question an excellent manner. THANKS!

Comment: @omokehindeigbekoyi It works for me in Ruby 2.7.2. Your mileage (and Ruby version) may vary.

Comment: `sprintf '%d, %d, %d', 1, 2, 3` works only on the commandline only when I use  the ruby the interpreter. When I write it in a file and run it from the commandline it works fine but the string doesn't output on the commandline. Why did you try running it from a file or did you type and run it in the ruby interpreter directly(irb)?

Comment: @omokehindeigbekoyi `sprintf` *returns* a string, it doesn't print one. If you want it on standard output, use `printf` instead.